# How to connect webservice to web interface?

Tags: java, spring, web-services

Assume we are designing a Spring webservice. We need to build also a web interface for it. As i understand, browser needs an HTML document to display it to user.

1. Can HTML be created on server and be sent as response to client's browser or only xml docs can be a response? Any details would be helpful.
2. If we need to process an XML response, build HTML and display it in browser, what is the most convenient way in Java context?

Comment: Build your API in Java and use Angular to consume the API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way you can make Spring boot restful web service and get json output from it and display it with Angular2. or you can use Spring Mvc and create web template with jsp pages and you can display it on browser.

[here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=video&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwixzKTGlNTRAhWIqI8KHV1nAe4QtwIIMDAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DsbPSjI4tt10&usg=AFQjCNGZe3_kk8S7FQfRwp5-vW3O7ZNpfg&sig2=M7PqhgTeRepuiYEu5RmcOA&bvm=bv.144224172,d.c2I) is the best video for follow spring boot

Answer (score 0):

1 - You can have static HTML on the server that is served as user requests your webpage.
2 - Add some javascript functions on the HTML pages to request your Spring java aplication endpoints and return response as json (or xml). For this purpouse Angular could be a good choice as stated above.